# Django database to postgresql

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, postgresql

There are around 5000 companies and each company has around 4500 prices, that makes a total of around 22,000,000 prices.

Now a while ago, I wrote a code that stored this data in a format like this-

```
class Endday(models.Model):
  company = models.TextField(null=True)
  eop = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50000)
```

And to store, the code was-

```
for i in range(1, len(contents)):
  csline = contents[i].split(",")
  prices = csline[1:len(csline)]
  company = csline[0]
  entry = Endday(company=company, eop=prices)
  entry.save()
```

Although, the code was slow(obviously) but it did work and stored the data in the database. One day, I decided to delete all the contents of Endday and tried to store again. But it did not work throwing me an error `Database locked`.

Anyway, I did a little research and got to know MySql can not handle this much of data. So how did it get stored in the first place? I came to a conclusion that all these prices were stored at the very beginning after which lot has stored in the database so this won't be getting stored.

After a little research, I got to know that I should use PostgreSql, so I changed the database, made migrations and moved on to try the code again but no luck. I got an error saying-

```
psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(50000)
```

Alright, so I thought lets try to use `bulk_create` and modified the code a bit but I was welcomed with the same error.

Next, I thought maybe lets make two models, one to hold the company names and other for the prices and the key to that particular company. So again, I changed the code-

```
class EnddayCompanies(models.Model):
  company = models.TextField(max_length=500)

class Endday(models.Model):
  foundation = models.ForeignKey(EnddayCompanies, null=True)
  eop = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

And the views-

```
to_be_saved = []
for i in range(1, len(contents)):
  csline = contents[i].split(",")
  prices = csline[1:len(csline)]
  company = csline[0]
  companies.append(csline[0])
  prices =[float(x) for x in prices]
  before_save = []
  for j in range(len(prices)):
    before_save.append(Endday(company=company, eop=prices[j]))
  to_be_saved.append(before_save)
Endday.objects.bulk_create(to_be_saved)
```

But to my surprise, this was so slow that in the middle, it just stopped on a company. I tried to find which particular code was slowing it down and it was-

```
before_save = []
  for j in range(len(prices)):
    before_save.append(Endday(company=company, eop=prices[j]))
  to_be_saved.append(before_save)
```

Well, now I am back to square one, and I can not think of anything, so I rang the bell of SO. The questions I have now-

- How to go by this?
- Why did the save work with MySql?
- Is there a better way to do this? (Of course there must be)
- If there is, what is it?

Comment: The data error you appear to have been getting is because eop was longer than 50k characters, not a problem with the actual saving. The database locked may have been to do with how you deleted the contents (i.e if you did this with a separate process).

Comment: So changing it to `TextField` does it but its slow and ineffective anyway

Comment: While you have made a very detailed question it still isn't a full MVCE. For example what does your input data look like? In other senses it's far too broad. There are 3 or 4 questions in there. Why don't you break  it up into different questions?

Comment: You also may want to read about 1NF : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @ThatBird just to clarify, what is the format of `contents`?

Comment: Contents is a line separated by commas, on 0 is the company name, from 1 till end are the prices.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a separate model for `Company`and `Price` something like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Price(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='prices')
    price = models.FloatField()
```

This is how you save the data:

```
# Assuming that contents is a list of strings with a format like this:
contents = [
    'Company 1, 1, 2, 3, 4...',
    'Company 2, 1, 2, 3, 4...',
    ....
]

for content in contents:
    tokens = content.split(',')
    company = Company.objects.create(name=tokens[0])
    Price.objects.bulk_create(
        Price(company=company, price=float(x.strip()))
        for x in tokens[1:]
    )
    # Then you can call prices now from company
    company.prices.order_by('price')
```

UPDATE: I just noticed that it is similar to your second implementation, the only difference is the way of saving the data.  My implementation has lesser iterations.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know

Comment: @ThatBird would be glad to know the result. :)